# How to include test classes in distZip?

Tags: gradle

I already have the following:

```
task packageTests(type: Jar) {
  from sourceSets.test.output
}
distZip {
    into(jarFolderName) {
        from '.'
        include 'conf/**'
    }   
    into(jarFolderName) {
        from '.'
        include 'bin/**'
        fileMode = 0755
    }
    into(jarFolderName) {
        from 'build'
        include 'logs'
    }
}
```

Adding a dependOn will create the test jar, but how can I then include it in the distribution zip file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Create tests jar:

```
task testJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'tests'
    from sourceSets.test.output
}
```

Step 2: Include it in distZip:

```
applicationDistribution.from(testJar) {
    into "tests"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works for me if I change `from sourceSets.test.classes` to `from sourceSets.test.output`.

Comment: Do you also know how I can create a distZip that also includes the test dependencies?

Comment: use the fat-jar plugin and customize the fatJar task (it's a Zip task) https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin

Comment: Thanks, but is there no easy way to have a second task (e.g. copy of distZip) that creates a zip including all the test relevant classes and jars?

Answer (score 1):

```
into(someFolder) {
    from packageTests
}
```

PS: I'd write the other `into`s like this:

```
into("$jarFolderName/conf") {
    from "conf"
}
    into("$jarFolderName/bin") {
    from "bin"
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I did change the into as you recommended.